# MacBook Pro Late 2011 Running Extremely Slow After Upgrade to SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance, macbook-pro, lvm

I have a late 2011 MacBook Pro that's currently running macOS Sierra 10.12.6 version. I updated the HDD(500GB) hard drive to an SSD Samsung 860 EVO(500GB) solid state hard drive. I had originally updated the hard drive, because the original HDD on it was failing, so I just replaced the entire thing. Originally, I was just getting a white grayish screen with a prohibition sign (a transparent circle with a line through it). It now works, but after all the updates, picking the drive under system settings, and restarting the system, it is extremely slow. When I select an icon such as something so simple, it brings up the search color wheel for about a minute or two. I think something might be off with the partitions, but I'm not too experienced with LVM, which is why I'm asking if anything looks off? I know Macintosh HD is showing as full, but I don't think it's that to be honest. I'll attach some screenshots on here. I'm sorry about the blurry images, I couldn't take a screenshot because the system was way to slow for even that.

[image: MacBook Screen Shot One]

[image: MacBook Screen Shot Two]

[DiskUtil List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65PiL.jpg)

Comment: What's puzzling me is why it's showing as a 'Logical volume' & why you would apparently use LVM on a Mac. How, precisely, did you format this? Can you get the results of `diskutil list` and `diskutil cs list` from Terminal? Copy/paste, select then Ctrl/K to format as 'code'. You might also be better aiming for High Sierra, as at least then it will understand APFS.

Comment: I'm actually confused in how it even got into Logical Volume as well. I did format it at the very beginning where you choose the GUID Partitions. I can get some of the diskutil lists on terminal, but the weird part is that I cannot go into the Macintosh HD folder, because supposedly it's not a directory or even a file I can view. I tried root permissions as well. Let me put some screenshots of the Diskutil lists on here.

Comment: @Tetsujin I added anther picture in the original post, since I cannot add a screenshot or picture into the comment section. But it shows up as a link to the picture, which I titled "DiskUtil List."

Comment: Hmmm. it might be something to do with Core Storage, but I have to admit I don't know much about that - I skipped the Sierras entirely, I hated them so much, & went from El Cap to Mojave.

Comment: @Tetsujin I would definitely agree that it has something to do with the core storage. Not as it is damaged, but something is not correct with the partitions. It is mounted, so that's not an issue, but I can't exactly tell because I don't know much about it either.